# Cannot update a component while rendering a different Component - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I know lots of developers had similar kinds of issues in the past like this. I went through most of them, but couldn't crack the issue.

I am trying to update the cart Context counter value. Following is the code(store/userCartContext.js file)

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const UserCartContext = createContext({
  userCartCTX: [],
  userCartAddCTX: () => {},
  userCartLength: 0
});

export function UserCartContextProvider(props) {
  const [userCartStore, setUserCartStore] = useState([]);

  const addCartProduct = (value) => {
    setUserCartStore((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, value];
    });
  };

  const userCartCounterUpdate = (id, value) => {
    console.log("hello dolly");
    // setTimeout(() => {
    setUserCartStore((prevState) => {
      return prevState.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, productCount: value };
        }
        return item;
      });
    });
    // }, 50);
  };

  const context = {
    userCartCTX: userCartStore,
    userCartAddCTX: addCartProduct,
    userCartLength: userCartStore.length,
    userCartCounterUpdateCTX: userCartCounterUpdate
  };

  return (
    <UserCartContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </UserCartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserCartContext;
```

Here I have commented out the `setTimeout` function. If I use setTimeout, it works perfectly. But I am not sure whether it's the correct way.

In `cartItemEach.js` file I use the following code to update the context

```
const counterChangeHandler = (value) => {
    let counterVal = value;
    userCartBlockCTX.userCartCounterUpdateCTX(props.details.id, counterVal);
};
```

CodeSandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-learnable-one-1z5td

Issue happens when I update the counter inside the `CART` popup. If you update the counter only once, there won't be any error. But when you change the counter more than once this error pops up inside the console. Even though this error arises, it's not affecting the overall code. The updated counter value gets stored inside the state in Context.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing in the console?

Comment: @DanielBeck, I have updated the CodeSandBox link. The warning I get is --  Warning: Cannot update a component (`UserCartContextProvider`) while rendering a different component (`Counter`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Counter`,

Comment: @DanielBeck I think the problem is in counter.js file(components > counter.js), where I am passing the value back to the parent component using ```props.onCounterChange();```

Comment: @DanielBeck Currently I am reworking on the counter component. Instead of props, I use object destructuring  `const Counter = ({counterType,currentCounterVal,onCartBtnPush,onCounterChange}) => {}`

and instead of calling the function `onCounterChange()` inside the `incrementHandler()` and `decrementHandler()` I am using useEffect  like this `useEffect(()=>{
        onCounterChange(number);
    },[number, onCounterChange])`

But this is also not working

Comment: Please show where `userCartCounterUpdateCTX` gets called. Likely it needs to be wrapped in `useEffect` or similar.

Comment: @edemaine  Inside `cartItemEach.js` component (components > cart > cartItemEach.js) [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-learnable-one-1z5td?file=/src/components/cart/cartItemEach.js)

Answer (score 0):

TIL that you cannot call a setState function from within a function passed into another setState function.  Within a function passed into a setState function, you should just focus on changing that state.  You can use `useEffect` to cause that state change to trigger another state change.

Here is one way to rewrite the `Counter` class to avoid the warning you're getting:

```js
  const decrementHandler = () => {
    setNumber((prevState) => {
      if (prevState === 0) {
        return 0;
      }
      return prevState - 1;
    });
  };

  const incrementHandler = () => {
    setNumber((prevState) => {
      return prevState + 1;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.onCounterChange(props.currentCounterVal);
  }, [props.currentCounterVal]);
  // or [props.onCounterChange, props.currentCounterVal] if onCounterChange can change
```

It's unclear to me whether the `useEffect` needs to be inside the `Counter` class though; you could potentially move the `useEffect` outside to the parent, given that both the current value and callback are provided by the parent.  But that's up to you and exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a helping hand. But it's not working. Now I am getting this warning: **index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.**

Comment: Can I ask you something? Inside userCartContext (store/userCartContext.js file), I have commented out the `setTimeout` function. If I use this, then it works perfectly. Can I use `setTimeout`? OR What's the issue if I use `setTimeout`?

Comment: Try removing `props.onCounterChange` from the `useEffect` dependency array, as in the revised code above. If that's defined as an inline function (without `useCallback` wrapping) it will change every time.